# Removing Chrome's "translate" DOM Property

Tags: javascript, html, magento, google-chrome, xpath

I'm working with some legacy code where the original developers made heavy use of generating HTML DOM nodes with a non-standard attribute named `translate`

```
<span translate="[{&quot;shown&quot;:&quot;My Account&quot;,&quot;translated&quot;:&quot;My Account&quot;,&quot;original&quot;:&quot;My Account&quot;,&quot;location&quot;:&quot;Text&quot;,&quot;scope&quot;:&quot;Mage_Customer&quot;}]">My Account</span>
```

and then traversing/searching for those nodes with javascript code like the following.

```
if (!$(target).match('*[translate]')) {
    target = target.up('*[translate]');
}
```

The problem I'm trying to solve is, it appears that Google Chrome **automatically** adds a `translate` attribute to every DOM node in the document, and that this DOM node's value is a boolean `true`.  You can see this by running the following Javascript from Chrome's javascript console

```
> document.getElementsByTagName('p')[0].translate
true
>
```

Is there anyway to tell Chrome **not** to populate these attributes?  Their presence is wrying havoc with the legacy code. PrototypeJS's `match` and `up` nodes treat these boolean object attributes as matches, while the code I'm dealing with is specifically looking for DOM nodes with an attribute named translate. I'd like to find a solution for my problem that doesn't involved rewriting the old Javascript to use methods like `hasAttribute`.

I tried (as a wild guess) adding the `meta` attributes mentioned in [this article](http://blog.pheromonic.com/web-development/the-translate-attribute/),

```
<meta name=”google” value=”notranslate”>
<meta name=”google” content=”notranslate”>
```

but the nodes in the page still has a boolean `true` translate attribute.

(if it matters, this is Magento's inline translation system I'm talking about here)

Comment: Have you tried adding the class `'notranslate'` to the elements you're  wanting to avoid? http://support.smartling.com/entries/20492913-how-to-exclude-content-from-translation

Comment: @B00MER 1. That would be every element on the page, so no.  2. Even with a class="notranslate", the javascript node is there and set to true.

Comment: there are http://api.jquery.com/prop/ and http://api.jquery.com/attr/ can you use these? chrome does not seem to add any attributes. just properties perhaps.

Comment: @akonsu Again, to echo my post, my concern isn't finding a replacement navigation/testing method, it's finding a way to make Chrome behave like other browsers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best I've been able to come up with so far is going through every DOM element in the page defining a getter that checks for the existence of an attribute. (the `Object.__defineGetter__` guard clause ensures no errors in browsers that don't support modern Javascript)

```
if(Object.__defineGetter__)
{
    var hasTranslateAttribute = function(){
        return $(this).hasAttribute("translate");
    };
    document.observe("dom:loaded", function() {
        $$('*').each(function(theElement){
             theElement.__defineGetter__("translate", hasTranslateAttribute);
        });
    });
}
```

I tried defining a getting on `Object.prototype` and `Element.prototype`, but it seems like the browser's native `translate` is defined higher up the chain, so you need to redefine things on a per element basis.

Answer (score 2):

Replace the nonstandard attribute `translate` by an attribute like `data-translate`, which is virtually guaranteed to be and to remain undefined in HTML specifications and in browsers. The [`data-*` attributes](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/global-attributes.html#embedding-custom-non-visible-data-with-the-data-%2a-attributes) were invented to prevent issues like this, and they can also be used to fix them.

Comment: +1 for good advice, but I'm specifically looking for a solution that doesn't involve me rewriting the legacy code at this particular moment in time.