# boolean is not a function in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following javascript where I am reading in a word and writing out a translation, but I keep getting the error `boolean is not a function`

```
function translate() {
var word = $("#prodId").val();

$.getJSON("api/translation?word=" + word,
            function (data) {

                $("#word").text(data.TranslatedWord);
            })
            .fail(
                function (jqXHR, textStatus, err) {
                    $("#word").text('Error: ' + err);
                });
                    }
```

The following method which is basically the same thing, but uses an integer works fine:

```
function find() {
       var id = $("#prodId").val();
       $.getJSON("api/products/" + id,
            function (data) {
                var str = data.Name + ': $' + data.Price;
                $("#product").text(str);
            })
            .fail(
                function (jqXHR, textStatus, err) {
                    $("#product").text('Error: ' + err);
                });
                    }
```

Here is a snippet of the HTML:

```
<div id="body">
    <div class="main-content">
        <div>
            <h1>All Products</h1>
            <ul id="products" />
        </div>
        <div>
        <label for="prodId">ID:</label>
        <input type="text" id="prodId" />
        <input type="button" value="Translate" onclick="translate();" />
        <p id="word" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    // Send an AJAX request
    $.getJSON("api/products/",
              function (data) {
                  // On success, 'data' contains a list of products.
                  $.each(data, function (key, val) {

                      // Format the text to display.
                      var str = val.Name + ': $' + val.Price;

                      // Add a list item for the product.
                      $('<li/>', { text: str })
                      .appendTo($('#products'));

                  });

              });

});

    function find() {
        var id = $("#prodId").val();
        $.getJSON("api/products/" + id,
                  function (data) {
                      var str = data.Name + ': $' + data.Price;
                      $("#product").text(str);
                  })
        .fail(
            function (jqXHR, textStatus, err) {
                $("#product").text('Error: ' + err);
            });
    }

    function translate() {
        var word = $("#prodId").val();

        $.getJSON("api/translation?word=" + word,
                  function (data) {

                      $("#word").text(data.TranslatedWord);
                  })
        .fail(
            function (jqXHR, textStatus, err) {
                console.log(err);

                $("#word").text('Error: ' + err);
            });
    }




</script>
```

Comment: Which line causes the error?

Comment: Don't you get some more details via a  browsers console, e.g. a line number or backtrace?

Comment: What does `console.log(data.TranslatedWord)` give you?

Comment: @Philipp - I don't know how to tell, but when I look at the google console, it occurs on the onclick

Comment: @KevinB - I tried putting that in the function, but nothing shows.

Comment: Where should I put console.log(data.TranslatedWord)?

Comment: Right before the line where it is used.

Comment: where are you calling this function? can you show that code?

Comment: it is called in the onlick event of the input button.

Comment: @KevinB - I put console.log(data.TranslatedWord); after function(data) { and nothing shows up in the console. Even if I put console.log("hi"); I don't see anything.

Comment: @Xaisoft that means you should be getting `$("#product").text('Error: ' + err);` ran. What does that print? If you place an alert there, does it get called?

Comment: You are overwriting the `translate` function with a boolean variable at some point. Please show more of your code (perhaps search for all occurrences of "translate" and show those lines and their context).

Comment: @Juhana - I just posted all the javascript.

Comment: What is `/api/translation`? How is the JSON being supplied?

Comment: In developer tools, add `translate` to the Watch Expressions. This will stop when this gets redefined, and that should help you see where it's happening.

Comment: /api/translation is from the ASP.NET WebAPI

Comment: weird, I can reproduce it even without any javascript, this is a great question see here: http://jsfiddle.net/SR8Z3/7/

Comment: looks like translate is some reserved word for chrome, changing the function to translatedWord worked.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems like the `onclick` isn't working.

Since you are already using jQuery I would suggest using the click event instead of having the `onclick` in the HTML.  It is better practice to do so...

Try something like this:

```
$("#translateButton").click(function() {
    translate();
});
```

And simply your HTML to this:

```
<input id="translateButton" type="button" value="Translate" />
```

Comment: The symptom suggests that something is redefining `translate` from a function to a boolean. Changing how the click handler is bound probably won't solve this.

Comment: This actually worked, but why does it not work the other way?

Comment: true... but from the code he has posted, we can't see what has redefined the translate function... so suggesting a different way of binding could solve it.

Comment: @Xaisoft... not sure, which browser are you using?

Comment: @c0deNinja - It works for the find function though, but not the translate function.

Comment: Maybe rename translate to translateWord??? haha not sure, maybe chrome is using translate()

Comment: lol, that has to be it, changing it to TranslateWord worked, so apparently translate is some reserved word in chrome.

Comment: rename function name work for me( Ex: translatioe > googleTranslate), i think translate function try to overriding. i used this same code block for translation.

Answer (score 7):

It seems that in chrome all elements have a boolean property called `translate`, (e.g. `console.log(document.body.translate)` will display `true` in chrome, not sure why.

When you do `onclick="translate();"` then it simply calls it on the local DOM object scope (now why doesn't it call it on the window object is another question)

e.g. if you change `translate` to `translate2` it should work, as weird as it sounds

Comment: translate is a reserved word in chrome. Changing it to translateWord worked.

Comment: yep, weird, I couldn't find any documentation on it, except this related SO question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13113914/removing-chromes-translate-dom-property

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you're defining your `translate()` function inside the `document.ready()` function. These function definitions are local to that scope, they can't be accessed from `onclick`.

You don't need to put function definitions inside the `ready` handler, you only need statements that access the DOM immediately in there. Define it at toplevel and it should work.

Or, as c0deNinja suggested, use jQuery to bind the handler. If you do this inside the `ready` handler, it can call other functions defined in there.

Comment: I took out the document.ready and the other function. When running it in IE, it works, but in chrome, it does not.

Comment: Thought so too, it's not, this is a tricky one see this http://jsfiddle.net/SR8Z3/7/ and look at the console